# Outlook 2013 Searching Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, sharing

I am trying to search ALL of the shared calendars on Outlook 2013 but it keeps just searching one a time, is there a way to search all of the calendars in one go?

Answer (score 0):

According to my test and research, I’m afraid that currently, we can only search in shared calendars using the Current Folder search scope.